# C - fread char from file

Tags: c, arrays, fread, chars

I have a dummy program which writes some chars in a file :

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char i = '0';
    int j = 0;
    FILE * fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen("num.txt","w+");
    if(!fp){
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);

    while(1){
        if (j >500) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        usleep(5000);
        fwrite(&i,sizeof(char),1,fp);
        if (j%27 ==0) {
            i ='0';
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And another program in which I need to read from that file, here is a fragment:

```
 if ((num = fopen("num.txt", "r+")) == NULL){
    perror("Error al obrir l'arxiu");   
}

fseek( num, posicio, SEEK_SET );
fread(resposta, sizeof(char), offset, fp);
while(contador <500){
    printf("%c",resposta[contador]);
    contador++;
}
printf(" la resposta contiene %s \n",resposta);A
```

I want to read "offset" chars from the position "posicio". "resposta" is an array of 500 chars.The while you can see in the second program is because I'm desperate, when I execute the second program,in the console appears a bunch of symbols such as : xMh��  in the last printf.

I tried to read byte to byte in the while, but it keeps getting me these symbols, I don't know what may be doing this, my first suspicion was that I was somehow opening the file in binary mode, but nope!

Comment: Ignoring the 1st program.  Put some plain text into "num.txt" and test the 2nd program with that.  Verify you're getting what is in the file. Are you seeking past the end of the file?  Check the return value of fread(), it should be equal to <offset>.

Comment: i need the fseek, i don't want to start reading from the start.And from normal text i keep getting the same incorrect outputs

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the (j % 27 == 0) - looping the letter i back to some point?

Comment: I keep getting wome weid problems reading withoout, beacuse I tried to read opening with byte mode before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a re-write of your first program with some nice formatting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char i = '0';
    int j = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("num.txt", "w+");
    /*fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);  - NOT NEEDED*/

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        for (j=0; j<500; j++)
        {
            usleep(5000);

            fwrite(&i, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
            fflush(fp);

            if (j % 27 == 0)
                i = '0';

            i++;  /* could be put in the for() loop header */
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And

```
void readBlock(int posicio, int offset, char *resposta)
{
    int i;
    FILE *num = fopen("num.txt", "r+");

    if (num != NULL)
    {
        /* reposition to <posicio> bytes from the start of the file */
        fseek(num, posicio, SEEK_SET);

        /* read <offset> bytes from that position */
        fread(resposta, sizeof(char), offset, num);

        fclose(num);

        /* dump out the bytes */
        for (i=0; i<offset; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", resposta[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Note that in your code snippet #2, you're opening the file with the handle in the variable ''num'', but then reading from the handle ''fp''.  Is that on purpose?  It looks like a bug, but is hard to say from here.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it that was a bug. But now i get the problem "too many open files"

Comment: Ah yep - I forgot the fclose().  If ever you have too many open files, you forgot this too.

Comment: BTW: I added that fflush() because I assume you're consuming the file in a separate thread or process as you read it.  Without the flush, you can't really know if/when the file has been written by the operating system.